# Facebook ordering app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have an online pizza ordering system.
Now the client wants to integrate it in facebook.
The idea is everyone who is browsing facebook to be able to click on our App and order directly instead of going to our domain.

I can see that there are similar apps in the facebook search:
for example Flippin' Pizza Ordering : https://apps.facebook.com/flippinpizzafb/

Its exactly what we need.
The problem is that when I login the facebook dev platform.
When I click create a new app the only possible way to open our website in iframe (in facebook app) is if I choose it as Facebook web games.
Is this what I need or it's something different?

Haven't followed facebook dev stuff for a long time.. and every time when I log in there everything is changed..

Comment: Just have people go to your website and use Facebook login there.

Comment: Not an option! Like I said the website must be opened inside facebook.

Comment: Yes, Facebook Web Games is what used to be called the Canvas platform.

Comment: Canvas is only for games. Your app is not a game. Also there is no way to do it on mobile anyway.